Why the `docker run --mount` does not generate an error when bind-mount a directory that does not yet exist on host?
I'm a novice in Docker and following the Docker Docs about Differences between -v and --mount behavior.
It says that:

If you use --mount to bind-mount a file or directory that does not yet exist on the Docker host, Docker does not automatically create it for you, but generates an error.

But in my practice, I've found that docker run --mount did not generate an error when bind-mount a directory that does not yet exist on the host.
For example, if in PowerShell(pwsh), consider to mount a sub-directory test-dir4(not yet exist) in the path  E:\Codes\Works\DockerTests\volume-and-bind-mount-test:
#pwsh
cd "E:\Codes\Works\DockerTests\volume-and-bind-mount-test"
ls 
#     Directory: E:\Codes\Works\DockerTests\volume-and-bind-mount-test

# Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
# ----                 -------------         ------ ----
# d----          2024/10/14    16:17                test-dir
# d----          2024/10/14    16:18                test-dir2
# d----          2024/10/14    16:27                test-dir3

docker run -d --mount type=bind,source=E:\Codes\Works\DockerTests\volume-and-bind-mount-test/test-dir4,target=/log nginx:latest

ls
#     Directory: E:\Codes\Works\DockerTests\volume-and-bind-mount-test

# Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
# ----                 -------------         ------ ----
# d----          2024/10/14    16:17                test-dir
# d----          2024/10/14    16:18                test-dir2
# d----          2024/10/14    16:27                test-dir3
# d----          2024/10/14    20:06                test-dir4

The sub-directory test-dir4 has been generated automatically without any WARNING or ERROR messages. It seems different from the description of
Differences between -v and --mount behavior.
I'm perplexed about it. Do I misunderstand the Doc?
My environment:

Windows11 23H2 22631.4317
WSL version: 2.3.24.0
Docker version 27.2.0, build 3ab4256, (WSL 2 backend, x86_64)

Thanks in advance.

It might be a WSL thing. When I try on Ubuntu, it fails with an error invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /home/hans/repos/docker-sandbox/test-dir4

@HansKilian Yes, I'm using WSL2 as the docker's backend. I will attach more details about my environment to my question.

Sidenote: -v will create a directory when non-existing in Ubuntu as well.
